# appearance of LibreOffice on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, appearance

These problem is concerning only the appearance of LibreOffice on Lubuntu.

I installed LO via the Software Centre of Lubuntu, but at the end there was a break (it was not finished). Later I tried to reinstall it via Synaptic Package Manager but it said:

```
E: Der dpkg-Prozess wurde unterbrochen; Sie müssen manuell »dpkg --configure -a« ausführen, um das Problem zu beheben. 
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

means dpkg-process was interrupted, do it manually to solve the problem. I did so and LO is working fine.

But now all the icons and menu labelling is very tiny in LO, too tiny.
That's the Problem.

The window design is not from the Lubuntu desktop, (reminding me to win2k). So I guess it's not compatible with lxsession which I activated before the installation (in order to enable Hibernate, what is perfect working).
I appreciate every Idea what I could do.

Comment: Great, I've installed libreoffice-gtk via synaptic and now it is looking as it used to be.

Comment: @DKBose: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: Flagging as duplicate! Thanks for the info @DKBose

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this small font problem (which I had just again):

```
$ sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3
$ sudo apt purge libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-gtk
```